# filter for null value not working for DB2 and Sybase

Tags: java, sql, db2

The Java based Application is using common select query to extract records from all databases. The records with null values for a particular column(here 'id') should get dropped.

This is the query:

`SELECT * from Employee WHERE 1=1  AND id IS NOT NULL  AND cast(id as varchar) !=''`

It works fine for all databases but gives SQLException for DB2.

The goal is :

1. Check if null and blank value is considered same in DB2/Sybase.
2. Modify the SQL query to make it work for DB2/Sybase

Comment: Which SQLException? Generally there is a root cause with an error that was given by the DBMS, it is vitally important that you post such information if you want to get any specific answers.

Comment: DB2 makes a distinction between null and blank values (or at least the iSeries version does) - I think Oracle might be the only one that behaves that way.  DB2 might be throwing on the `!=` - if you're attempting to make a "universal query", you're going to have problems when you get to date/time operations (nobody does them exactly the same way).

Answer (score 0):

Although this won't affect your problem, I would use the `<>` operator instead of `!=` (the former is definitely part of the standard; I'm not sure if newer versions of the standard insist on `!=` being supported):

```
SELECT *
from Employee
WHERE 1=1  AND id IS NOT NULL AND id <> '';
```

The next suspicious thing is comparing an `id` to a string.  If `id` is a string, then no problem.  However, if it is numeric, you might have a type incompatibility.  Try one of these `where` clauses:

```
WHERE 1=1  AND id IS NOT NULL AND id <> 0;
```

or

```
WHERE 1=1  AND id IS NOT NULL AND cast(id as varchar(255)) <> '';
```

Comment: id was just an example. The field can be integer or varchar

Comment: @SID . . . Unfortunately, I don't have either database on hand to figure out the problem.  This was a best-guess, because the query looks pretty simple and should run on any database.  If typing is the problem, then the last `where` clause should work.

Comment: I modified the query to cast int column to text for blank check and it is working for Sybase. But still i am not able to run this on DB2